# Multiline freespace regular expression in YAML

Tags: regex, yaml

How can I insert a multiline freespace regular expression in YAML?

```
patterns:
  - match: |
    (?x)          # Ignore Comments
    %             # % Escape Character
    [#0\- +]*     # Prefix and Alignment Flags
    \d*           # Minimum field width
    (\.\d+)?      # Maximum precision
    [diouxXCcsp%] # Conversion type
```

The parser fails on the first `(` of `(?x)` with:

> Error parsing YAML: while scanning a simple key

and the `%` on the following line with:

> could not found expected ':'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex needed further indention:

```
patterns:
  - match: |
      (?x)          # Ignore Comments
      %             # % Escape Character
      [#0\- +]*     # Prefix and Alignment Flags
      \d*           # Minimum field width
      (\.\d+)?      # Maximum precision
      [diouxXCcsp%] # Conversion type
```